# OR tools C++: solver.MutableObjective() returns null

Tags: c++, null, or-tools

I just inherited a piece of code, which solves a mixed integer programming problem using OR Tools. Integrating OR Tools into VS 2019 was a headache of its own (well, I'm not that used to C++). Now the program is running, but I am getting:

> Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000020

According to the debugger, it looks like `solver.MutableObjective()` is returning null.

Other functions like `MakeRowConstraint` seem to work fine though, and they don't return null. Any clue what's going on? Could it be something I misconfigured when installing the library maybe?

```
MPSolver solver("simple_mip_program", MPSolver::SCIP_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING);
//...
MPObjective* FObj = solver.MutableObjective(); // <-- NULL

//therefore the below throws exception.
//The arrays `variables` and `F` are populated as expected
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) FObj->SetCoefficient(variables[i], F[i]);
FObj->SetMaximization();
```

---

**Edit:** A little more details, I am using ORTools 64bit_v8.1.8487, on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019.

I also tried running the [sample MIP problem from GitHub](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/linear_solver/samples/simple_mip_program.cc), and same error occurred on line 54.

Comment: did it work if you are using the glop solver ? pretty sure you didn't have the USE_SCIP define defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is more of a workaround.

The ORTools library download comes with example programs and a Makefile. So, I replaced the contents of one of the sample files with the code I need, and used the supplied Makefile to compile/run the program.

This way, the exact same code I had is not showing errors anymore. So, I guess the problem was a linking/import issue somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exactly same settings: ORTools 64bit_v8.1.8487, on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019.

To reproduce the question, run the sample code "examples/cpp/linear_programming_example.cc" in Visual Studio 2019. (with .lib and includes/ included into the property.)

I solve the problem by-

1. changing the C++ compiler to C++17 (default: 14) and
2. adding flags " /D_SILENCE_CXX17_OLD_ALLOCATOR_MEMBERS_DEPRECATION_WARNING /D_SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS "
   when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call Minimize() or Maximize() before to create the objective.

Comment: Kindly see edit. Even the demo code on GitHub gives me the same error

Comment: And, call `Maximize()` on which object? On the solver, like `solver.Maximize()`?

Comment: actually no, the MPObjective is initialize when the solver is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate the lib in your own project you also need the correct flags

```
 CXXFLAGS = /std:c++17 /EHsc /MD /nologo /D_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -nologo $(DEBUG) \ 
   /DPSAPI_VERSION=1 /D__WIN32__ /DNOMINMAX /DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS \ 
   /DGOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL= \ 
   /I$(INC_DIR)\\src\\windows /I$(INC_DIR) /I. \ 
   /DUSE_BOP /DUSE_GLOP \ 
   /DUSE_CBC /DUSE_CLP \ 
   /DUSE_SCIP
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/fa84bc05e72641dddfbb98164d81b8bc9bef6ea5/tools/Makefile.cc.java.dotnet#L126-L132